# Razor Pages - Routing from old page to new one

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using "razor pages" with asp.net core.

In one of my pages called "MyNewPage" I have the following piece of code:

```
    public void OnGetTest(string MyParam)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

To execute it I simply go to: /MyNewPage?handler=Test&MyParam=abc

This works perfectly fine. What I would like to do now is to map an old URL to it. For example:

```
     /MyOldPage/xyz should map to  /MyNewPage?handler=Test&MyParam=xyz
```

In Startup.cs I would like to write something like this in ConfigureServices but it doesn't work. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
     options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/MyNewPage?handler=Test&MyParam={text}", "/MyOldPage/{text}");
```

Comment: I assume your page have multiple Get handlers: OnGet and OnGetTest, right?

Comment: @Artem yes I have multiple Get handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Url Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).
Here what the code in your `Startup.Configure` method will look like:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions();
options.AddRewrite("MyOldPage/(.*)", "MyNewPage/?handler=Test&MyParam=$1", false);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

You should tweak the regular expression `(.*)` as necessary, to match to pattern or the URL to redirect from.

Comment: Thanks @Artak. I've tweaked the regular expression and it works fine. I've added a carat (^) at the beginning of the expression to make sure that only MyOldPage/etc is matched and not, for example, BlahBlahMyOldPage/etc   I've also changed the last parameter (skipRemainingRules) to true as recommended on the page you linked to.